# Working with NSMutableString (Beginner)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm working with a NSMutableString and having some difficulties. The app quits whenever i try to access it and it does not say that anything is amiss in the NSLog.

I set up the string in the view did load method so that my string will be able to retain its information rather than being reset, but i don't believe my knowledge on this is correct. Any help would be great. Thanks!

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class rootViewController;

@interface Numpad : UIViewController {

    rootViewController *viewController;

    UIButton *one;
    UIButton *two;
    UIButton *three;

    NSInteger *loggedNumbers;
    NSMutableString *numberString;
}

-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender;


@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UIButton *one;
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UIButton *two;
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UIButton *three;

@property (nonatomic, retain) rootViewController *viewController;


@end
```

and the .m

```
#import "Numpad.h"


@implementation Numpad

@synthesize viewController, one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, zero;

- (void)initString{

}

- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender{


    int stringLength = [numberString length];

    //NSLog(@"Number String before Switch: %@", numberString);  

    switch (((UIButton*)sender).tag){

        case 1:
            {
                [numberString insertString: @"1" atIndex: stringLength];
            }
        break;

        case 2:
            {
                [numberString insertString: @"2" atIndex: stringLength];
            }
            break;

        case 3:
            {
                [numberString insertString: @"3" atIndex: stringLength];
            }
            break;

        default:
        break;
    }


    double myDouble = [numberString doubleValue];
    int myInt = (int)(myDouble + (myDouble>0 ? 0.5 : -0.5));

    NSLog(@"Number String: %@", numberString);  
    NSLog(@"After int applied: %i", myInt);
}




/*
 // The designated initializer.  Override if you create the controller programmatically and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
*/


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {   
    numberString = [[NSMutableString stringWithString: @""];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just casting the `tag` to a `double`? Why are you using a string as a middleman?

Comment: the reason is that this is some kind of keyboard implementation. Press 1 2 3 and the string (and the double) is 123 where a casted tag would be 3.

Comment: since you are a beginner I think it's not too late to suggest you to follow the [naming conventions](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000082.php) and to start class names with a capital letter. It makes reading your code much easier. Once you learn about class methods you will understand why I suggest this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string do not retain by itself, as you are assigning value to numberString by convenience method so you should retain it yourself. So viewDidLoad should look like this.

```
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {   
    numberString = [[[NSMutableString stringWithString: @""] retain];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

or you should allocate it

```
numberString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString: @""] retain];
```

Comment: Also, you may want to use -[NSMutableString appendString:] instead of insertString:AtIndex: if all you want to do is to append something.

Comment: @puzzle yes right as if you need to append at end for string so appendString is better choice than insertString: AtIndex

Answer (score 1):

You need to retain your string when you init it.